# Can group layers be published to ArcGIS Server as a single object?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, group-layer

*ArcGIS Desktop/ArcGIS Server 10.7.1:*

I have 200 layers that I generate via ArcPy on a weekly basis (from an external source).

- The layers are grouped by *group layers* (roughly 10 layers per group).

---

My team plans to serve up the layers to an external system via ArcGIS Server.

However, I don't think it's wise to manually publish all 200 layers each week. There would be too much room for error and it would take too much time.

As someone who is new to ArcGIS Server/web GIS, I'm wondering,  is it possible to publish group layers as a single object, rather than as individual layers?

- That would allow my team to publish 20 objects/layers each week, instead of 200 objects/layers. I think that would be much easier to manage.

Comment: I would expect so.  In general I find many operations possible on individual layers are also possible on group layers.  I think you should try it.

Comment: You really ought to try publishing before deciding what's too hard. In fact, publishing one layer has the same difficulty as publishing a thousand. Also, group layers don't function the way you seem to want (their real benefit is as a way of toggling display). Accessing data from multiple services requires only a little additional effort, but AGS performance is linked to the number of services, so there is a clear law of diminishing returns with respect to multiple services for a single dataset.